# How to round a square image and put it on video

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I've a video, videoPath.
I've a square image, squarePath.

This code places the squarePath on the video at a desired position to output, outputVideo.

```
final String[] cmd = new String[]{"-i", videoPath, "-i", squarePath, "-filter_complex", "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(300/300)*175:175[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(343)", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-c:a", "copy", "-y", outputVideo};

int res = FFmpeg.execute(cmd);
```

I would like to round the squarePath in the same command. Is it possible?

This is the code to make it rounded as I found:

```
ffmpeg -i avatar.png -i mask.png -filter_complex [0]scale=400:400[ava];[1]alphaextract[alfa];[ava][alfa]alphamerge output.png
```

but I don't understand how to merge these two commands.

Answer (score 0):

filtergraph should look something like this:

```
[1:v][2:v]alphamerge[ovly]; \
[ovly][0:v]scale2ref=(300/300)*175:175[wm][base]; \
[base][wm]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(343)
```

The 3rd input `[2:v]` should be a grayscale image with the same size as the overlay input (`[1:v]`) and its pixels value to be 255 where the overlay image shall see through and 0 elsewhere. The `alphamerge` filter adds this grayscale image as the alpha plane of the overlay image.